# SBT classpath dependency with ScalaJS crosscompile project

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-compiling, scala.js

I have 2 different separate projects A and B, both of which use the ScalaJS default way of wiring cross compile projects (see here: https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/cross-build.html).

Now I want to add a SBT Classpath Dependency from B to A in a manner similar to this:

```
projectA.dependsOn(projectB)
```

where the `js` part of project B can use the `js` and `shared` parts of project A and the `jvm` part can access `jvm` and `shared` parts of project A.

As I am using `upickle` for serializing my data, I cannot just use a `libraryDependeny` with a `publishLocal`of project A (as `upickle` requires compile time information about project A in my case).

How can I solve this?

Comment: The default `.dependsOn` between `CrossProject` should give you exactly that behavior.

Comment: can I build a `CrossProject` from an `uri` (like a normal root project), so that I can pull it from a remote git repo? The documentation for CrossProject is really minimal and I did not find any factory methods/constructors yet.

Comment: `CrossProject` is a factory to create two sbt projects within your `build.sbt`, one for the JVM, one for JavaScript, while sharing some settings and other definitions. There is no pulling from remote repositories going on at this point. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Project A and project B do not share a directory structure, meaning they are separate on disk (or on different remote git repositories). The question comes down to how to create a `CrossProject` from a `File` or a `Uri` just as `RootProject` can be build from both kinds of references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `CrossProject`'s in the same build, you can simply use `.dependsOn`:

```
lazy val a = crossProject
lazy val b = crossProject.dependsOn(a)

// snip aJS, aJVM, bJS, bJVM
```

Currently, there is no way to import a `CrossProject` from a URI / File like a `RootProject`. However, a `CrossProject` is nothing more than a two normal sbt projects. You can import these individually:

```
// a.sbt

lazy val a = crossProject
lazy val aJS = a.js
lazy val aJVM = a.jvm

// b.sbt

lazy val b = crossProject.
  jsConfigure(_.dependsOn(aJS)).
  jvmConfigure(_.dependsOn(aJVM))

lazy val aJS = ProjectRef(file("projectA"), "aJS")
lazy val aJVM = ProjectRef(file("projectA"), "aJVM")
```

Note that there doesn't seem a reason we cannot create a `CrossProjectRef` that abstracts this away from you. So if you need this often, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/new) so we can look at it in more detail.

Comment: I think configureJS got renamed to jsConfigure and configureJVM got renamed to jvmConfigure